# terraform_remote_state: Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Scenario: I am trying to read remote terraform state which is stored in AWS S3 bucket. I have configured aws credentials using aws configure cli and using the credentials I am able to read AWS S3 bucket and object of tf state.

terraform init is working fine. But when I run terraform plan I am getting the following error:

```
Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found.
│
│ Please see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
│       For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

│

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-1"
  profile = "dev-token"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "ekscluster_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "bucket"
    region = "ap-southeast-1"
    key = "remote.tfstate"
  }
}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "db_subnet_ids" {
  name = data.terraform_remote_state.ekscluster_state.outputs.db_subnet_ids
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "aurora_subnet_group" {
  name       = "name"
  subnet_ids = data.aws_eks_cluster.db_subnet_ids

  tags = {
    Name = format("%s", "name")
  }
}
```

Remote state contains all the content. Note: storing state on S3 is working fine with same credentials.

Looking forward to hear some hint.

Comment: Have you considered using the [`aws_subnet_ids` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet_ids) instead of using Terraform's remote state? Using proper provider specific data sources where possible is nearly always a better solution and will work much more easily.

Comment: If you really do want to use the remote state data source then you will need to also align the configuration of that with the configuration of the remote state backend as they are handled separately. You haven't shown your remote state backend configuration but if it matches the provider configuration you will also need to add the `profile` key to the `config` block.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `terraform_remote_state` [argument-reference docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/remote-state-data.html#argument-reference)

> The config object can use any arguments that would be valid in the equivalent terraform { backend "" { ... } } block

So you likely need to specify the profile as part of the `terraform_remote_state` blocks `config` element, e.g.:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "ekscluster_state" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "bucket"
    region = "ap-southeast-1"
    key = "remote.tfstate"
    profile = "dev-token"
  }
}
```

FWIW to avoid this I generally try to set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable when running my TF scripts. I manage a *lot* of different AWS accounts with different profiles so I specify inline when calling TF.

Comment: How are you using AWS_PROFILE ? as an environment variable ?

Comment: @Judi - yes just using an envvar AWSPROFILE=my-profile. I often set inline to avoid the possibility of using the wrong one. e.g. (`$env:AWS_PROFILE='dev-token';terraform plan`)

Comment: I will probably start a separate thread to get some more thoughts on this issue. Your approach is fine. However, looks like you are using PS - correct? This has always been my fear that I might forget to change my env and my TF could run in a diff env.

Comment: Mostly using PS but sometimes bash. I don't worry about forgetting to change so much as the different profiles generally don't have access to each others state files. Also, when I run a plan I can see what the changes will be.